# jQuery - Detecting specific length words in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, is there a simpler method to detect if a string has words with X amount if characters or less? I'm about to write some Javascript that loops through each word in the string, checking each individual length, but want to know if there is a function, or a simpler method, possibly in jQuery, before I waste time and lines.

This is what I was going to do, there must be an easier method, possibly a one-liner?

```
var bad_words = 0;
var search_str = $('#search_str').split(' ');
$.each(search_str, function(index, chunk) {
    if (chunk.length < 4) {
        bad_words++;
    }
}
if (badwords > 0) {
    alert("Words with 3 or less characters found.");
}
```

I'm not looking for somebody to do my work, I just want to know if it's possible, and if so, what should I be looking at.

Comment: @DanielA.White: I haven't. That's why I'm here asking if it's possible? I'm quite happy to do the work, I just wanna know where to start and look.

Comment: its possible. you don't need jquery for it.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid: Where to start and look? I dunno...[the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)? Any number of [meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) sites?

Comment: All people had to say was: "No. There is no simple function to check in jQuery, you will need to loop through each word and check manually." Jeez, this site can be overly moderated sometimes.

Comment: You didn't learn anything. You don't have to loop over anything when evaluating a string for a condition when using RegExp. Also, this isn't a `yes/no` answer site. This is not a forum. We're not `overly moderated`, we just prefer to have a community that adheres to guidelines. This is no exception.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: One, I did learn something. I learned that I don't need to loop through each word, I can use RegEx instead. Two, before you shout off about adhering to the guidelines; you have written two questions and one of them fails *the guidelines* under the 'too localized' rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (str.match(/\b\w{1,3}\b/g)) {
  // string has words with 3 chars or less
}
```

Comment: +1 Niiiiiice... (The OP should have at least *tried*, but that doesn't take away from the sheer elegance of this solution.)

Comment: +1 nice, very nice. I only started a solution to practice my REGEX and just learned about `\b` - word boundaries.

Comment: Actually if just testing for existence since `match` returns `null` if not found, it can be even shorter!

Answer (score 3):

```
/\b\w{1,3}\b/.test(str)
```

Simply returns `true` or `false`, as you wish.

Comment: +1 @PaparazzoKid This is by far the best answer. To answer your second question you want to learn [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: I think that you must learn regexps, not me. But thanks

Comment: I agree which is why I added `@PaparazzoKid` which addresses the comment to the OP @PaparazzoKid. You clearly know your REGEX.